# When analyzing complexity - is the base of the logarithm significant?

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o, time-complexity

While writing the complexity of an algorithm to be in terms of logarithm, e.g. Merge Sort is O(nlogn).

What is the base of the logarithm, does it matter, why?

Comment: Tips: use a spell-checker and think at least 1 sec about what tags to use.

Comment: What does it have to do with Windows?

Comment: Algorithms run on Windows use base 10; Linux uses base 2.

Answer (score 3):

The base of the logarithm does not matter.

The next equation hold for all m,n,k<sup>1</sup>:

```
log_m(n) = log_k(n)/log_k(m)
```

Since `1/log_k(m)` is constant, everything which is `log_k(n)` is also `log_m(n)`. This is true for *all k,m* thus - the base of the logarithm does not matter when using big O notation, since `O(log_k(n)) = O(log_m(n))`

---

(1) for more details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base

Answer (score 2):

In O and Omega notation, logs with different constant bases are equivalent. This is because the difference is constant and constants are ignored.

See. [Big O Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)